# Getting Attempted relative import in non-package error in spite of having __init__.py

Tags: python, python-2.7, osx-lion

I have a package `cclogger`. This directory has a `__init__.py` file with some code to load the configuration. When I try to run the file `api_main.py` in that directory using the following command...

```
python -m cclogger.api_main
```

I get the following erro:-

```
config loaded
Instantiating DB with: cclogger/test123@localhost:x
Instantiated ParseCentral
Register parser called by : CitiIndia
Registered parser for email:  CitiAlert.India@citicorp.com
Instantiated SmsParseCentral
Register parser called by : Citi Bank
Registered sms parser for address:  lm-citibk
Register parser called by : HDFC Bank
Registered sms parser for address:  am-hdfcbk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/applegrew/Dropbox/Credit Expense/cclogger/cclogger/api_main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .bottle import run, default_app, debug, get
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

The messages displayed above the error are from modules in the same package which were imported by `__init__.py`.

The code in api_main.py is:-

```
import re
import os

from .bottle import run, default_app, debug, get
from .common_util import date_str_to_datetime, UTCOffset, date_filter

#app = Bottle()

default_app().router.add_filter('date', date_filter)

from . import api, dev

@get('/index')
def index():
    return "CCLogger API main live and kicking."

if dev:
    debug(True)
    run(reloader=True, port=9000)
else:
    os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    application = default_app()
```

I have python 2.7.1.

What am I doing wrong? You can see the full code at https://github.com/applegrew/cclogger/tree/master/cclogger

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot run a python module directly as a script (I don't really know the reason why).

**EDIT** : The reason is explained in the [PEP338](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0338/) which is the spec for the `"-m"` option.

> The release of 2.5b1 showed a surprising (although obvious in
>   retrospect) interaction between this PEP and PEP 328 - explicit
>   relative imports don't work from a main module. This is due to the
>   fact that relative imports rely on `__name__` to determine the current
>   module's position in the package hierarchy. In a main module, the
>   value of `__name__` is always `__main__` , so explicit relative imports
>   will always fail (as they only work for a module inside a package).
>
> **For the 2.5 release, the recommendation is to always use absolute imports in any module that is intended to be used as a main module**

To test your application, encapsulate api_main in a function and create a top-level main.py file which will run the main loop :

**cclogger/api_main.py :**

```
import re
import os


from .bottle import run, default_app, debug, get
from .common_util import date_str_to_datetime, UTCOffset, date_filter

#app = Bottle()


def main():
    default_app().router.add_filter('date', date_filter)

    from . import api, dev

    @get('/index')
    def index():
        return "CCLogger API main live and kicking."

    if dev:
        debug(True)
        run(reloader=True, port=9000)
    else:
        os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))
        application = default_app()
```

And **/main.py** :

```
from cclogger import api_main


if __name__ == '__main__':
    api_main.main()
```

You can run your application by typing `python main.py`, `python -m main` or `python -c "import cclogger.api_main; api_main.main()"` .

PS : thanks for linking the complete source, it's always much more helpful than the stubs provided with the question.

Comment: It don't work for me. (same reason: Relative import in a non-package)

Comment: This accepted answer is incorrect (or rather out of date - it's probably true for Python 2.5, but the OP stated Python 2.7). Please refer to my answer.

Comment: @Manganeez : This is still valid for 2.7. There is forward compatibility for 2.xx specs (or if you prefer 2.xx implementations are backward compatibles).

Comment: @georgesl I'm sorry, I don't understand. Backward compatibility means that things that worked before continue to work - it doesn't mean that things that didn't work before must not work now. 2.7 clearly introduces lots of new syntax, for example (such as set literals and dict comprehensions). Your assertion that because the "-m" flag was incompatible with relative imports in 2.5, it must still be so in 2.7, but this is demonstrably false. PEP-366 explicitly states that this incompatibility was rectified in 2.6. Did you look at my answer? Apologies if I've misunderstood what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

Relative imports work fine in modules executed using `python -m` since Python 2.6. As explained in http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366, the `__package__` attribute is automatically set on the module when executed this way so that relative imports work. The piece that's causing the failure here is the reloader, which apparently fails to set `__package__`.

Edit: Glancing at the code, I see that this is a bottle API. I didn't check bottle, but it likely has the same problem as Flask's reloader, which attempts the restart by trusting what's in `sys.argv`. The problem is that the code that handles `python -m` (which is in the `runpy` module) modifies `sys.argv`, removing the "-m" and translating the module name to a filename (which is very frustrating, but I'm sure they had good reason). Thus, what the reloader actually executes has no "-m" and the bit that sets `__package__` never fires, resulting in no support for relative imports.